# POSIX C/C++ Logfiles (VEX V5 Brain)

Tags: c++, text, posix

Our VEX Robotics team is looking to start log files of the motor's performance (current/temperature)  ([here's an example of file handling on 'brain'](https://www.vexforum.com/t/v5-robotic-brain-sd-card/49152/15))

With not knowing how the brain will be shut down we need to open write and close the file.  With possible CPU/memory limitations we would like to keep logfiles as small as possible

Our thought is either:

A - on startup append a history file with the last log and clear the log file

B - on startup do a loop looking for 1.txt, 2.txt until not found
C - anything better!

I've looked extensively and find many solutions are not applicable to the VEX Brain.  The IDE is C++ and suspect only POSIX-libraries can be used.

The Brain / IDE doesn't appear to have a date or timestamp capabilities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the VEX platform offer POSIX file descriptor-based functions such as `open()`, `write()`, and `close()`?  Given your "possible CPU/memory limitations", using C++ streams probably should be avoided if possible.  Also, C++ streams and C `FILE *`-based functions tend to be buffered.  While this can be disabled, any buffering will conflict with "not knowing how the brain will be shut down we need to open write and close the file".  If you use POSIX `open()`/`write()`/`close()`, you don't really need to do that, assuming the VEX platform file system implementation is reasonably good.

Comment: Thanks! - I'll look into this.  I thought POSIX was the C++ variant of ANSI C but suspect I'm wrong here - POSIX seems to be UNIX, this is ARM-Based IDK_WT*_OS it is..  Guess I ping the forum....

Answer (score 0):

For A you could just open the same log file for appending:

```cpp
ofs.open("a_long_filename_debug.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

B is fine as well. Just a log rotation strategy.

Comment: Thanks.  However given the nature of a competition / tweens the file could easily grow too large & limit performance.  I tried B but converting an integet to a string & concatenating is proving a bugger - again I find examples but nothing POSIX-compliant